# Proof of eigenvalue stability inequality via Courant-Fischer min-max theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

T. Tao in [his notes on eigenvalue inequalities uses Courant-Fischer min-max theorem to prove the eigenvalue stability inequality](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/).  Specifically, I am looking for proof of Eq. (13) where he states as an immediate result of Eq. (6) and (10).  But the problem is that the min-max function is not convex. I have read Stewart & Sun's book on *Matrix Perturbation Theory*, but it seems that they have felt that it is obvious too.

Can someone provide more details on how to derive Eq. (13)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a simple and repeated application of $\min$ and $\max$ operators.

$$v^*(A+B)v=v^*Av+v^*Bv\le v^*Av+\|B\|_{op},\,\forall v\in R^n\wedge |v|=1.$$
Given $V$ where $\dim(V)=i$,
$$\min_{u\in V,|u|=1}u^*(A+B)u\le v^*(A+B)v\le v^*Av+\|B\|_{op},\,\forall v\in V\wedge |v|=1,$$
then
$$\min_{u\in V,|u|=1}u^*(A+B)u\le \min_{v\in V,|v|=1}v^*Av+\|B\|_{op}\le \max_{\dim(V)=i}\min_{v\in V,|v|=1}v^*Av+\|B\|_{op}$$
and
$$\max_{\dim(U)=i}\min_{u\in V,|u|=1}u^*(A+B)u\le \max_{\dim(V)=i}\min_{v\in V,|v|=1}v^*Av+\|B\|_{op}.$$
In other words
$$\lambda_i(A+B)\le\lambda_i(A)+\|B\|_{op}.$$
Similarly, we can prove
$\lambda_i(A)-\|B\|_{op}\le\lambda_i(A+B)$
and reach the desired inequality.